# NSFetchRequest release causes app to crash

Tags: iphone, memory-management, crash, memory-leaks, nsfetchrequest

The static analyzer keeps telling me that I have a +1 retain count for my request object and instruments tells me there is a leak there. However, no matter where I try to release it, it keeps crashing my app. It's the same with NSPredicate object. Please do help, I'm trying to meet a deadline.

```
// Fetch Requests

// Method that returns an array of NSManagedObjects in the managedObjectContext with a predicate of who ordered

- (NSArray *)fetchDataWithEntity:(NSString *)entity andSortKey:(NSString *)key andPerson:(Person *)whoOrdered

{

 NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

 NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entity 

                                                                   inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

 request.entity = entityDescription;



 // Handling Sorting

 NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:key ascending:YES 

                                                                                 selector:@selector(compare:)];

 NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

 [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

 [sortDescriptor release];

 [sortDescriptors release];



 // Handling Predicate

 if (whoOrdered) {

      NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@ == whoOrdered", whoOrdered];

      [request setPredicate:predicate];

 }



 NSError *error = nil;

 NSArray *mutableFetchResults = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

 //[request release];

 [error release];

 if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {

      // Handle the error

 }

 return mutableFetchResults;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to release the `error` object since you are not the owner of it and you should release the `request` object just before returning the `mutableFetchResults` object since you are creating it using `alloc` and thus are the owner of it ...

Comment: Thanks for noticing that, but it still doesn't work. Where ever I try to release request, it crashes. I also get 56.73% [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"...", whoOrdered]]; as a source of my leak.